# Please tell why the output of the below program is JKLM?? and not MLKJ?

Tags: c, unix, bitwise-operators, shift

```
Please explain the output of below program....

int main()
{
unsigned int i=0,j=0;
char c = 'J';
         i = (unsigned int) c;
         i|=(unsigned int) (c+1)<<8;
         i|= (unsigned int) (c+2) <<16;
         i|= (unsigned int) (c+3) <<24;
printf("\n%s",&i);
}
```

The output of the above program is showing as JKLM please explain why??

Answer (score 7):

Standardese nitpicking answer: because your program has undefined behavior. The `%s` conversion specifier expects a `char *` or an `unsigned char *` argument, but you pass it an `unsigned int *`.

Look-behind-the-curtains answer: your machine is probably little endian, so the least significant byte has the lowest memory address.

Comment: If H2CO3 says it (other than not casting malloc's), you should listen.

Comment: @xaxxon I am sure you will like my bio on my Twitter profile, go check it out :P

Comment: yeah, I was actually checking that out a few weeks ago and noticed.

Comment: @H2CO3 sometimes when I read your posts, you tend to come across like a blunt bully, but then again what would we expect from a person that is confronted on a daily basis with some much idiocy and inconsiderate stupidity as on SO, and I proceed to laugh heartily and enjoy your comments

Answer (score 3):

Your system seems to be little endian (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). This means that the least significant byte (the byte without shift) is the first byte in the character array which %s expects.